# send application logs to splunk using udp protocol

Tags: go, udp, splunk

I am working on service written on golang and I need to send log to splunk using udp protocol.
To write log into file and syslog I use github.com/sirupsen/logrus. There is the hook for splunk, github.com/Franco-Poveda/logrus-splunk-hook, but it using http protocol(POST verb) to send logs.
Could you advise me how to send logs to splunk using udp protocol.

Thank you!

Comment: You will most likely have to write your own package to do this.

Comment: I think so too. I haven't found any package by now. Do you know reference to splunk protocol specification?

Answer (score 1):

There is no published Splunk protocol since it's proprietary.
You can use UDP to send to Splunk using the syslog protocol, but a better approach is to save your logs to a file and have a Splunk Universal Forwarder send the file to Splunk.
Another option is to use HTTP to send data to a Splunk instance that is running an HTTP Event Collector (HEC).  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector#Send_data_to_HTTP_Event_Collector for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I gonna try it. But if splunk protocol is proprietary how other loggers work with it? For example for .net core there is NLog just configure Network target: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Webservice-Target-for-Splunk.
Network target is able to work not only with splunk but  for example kibana too. We only need to change address. Is there common approach to send network logs without  binding to certain platforms?

Comment: The two NLog examples use JSON over HTTP Event Collector (HEC) and plain text over TCP/UDP, respectively.  You can use either in your code, I gave you link to the HEC docs, but there is no "spec" for text over UDP.